# Как реализовать сеттер свойства с помощью лямбда-выражения?

Tags: c#, .net

Вот такой код в C# 6

```
public int Property => _property;
```

будет равнозначен этому:

```
public int Property {
   get { return _property; }
}
```

А возможно ли подобная реализация сеттера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже что нет. В соответствии со [статьёй](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

> You can also implement read-only (getter only) properties using expressions—expression bodied properties.

То есть для сеттера такая реализация пока не планируется.